# Install Az module in the packages for a project in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, powershell-az-module

I am trying to install the Az Module to use Az.Accounts commands and few others. I want to install the module for one specific project and be able to see that as a project depedency in the solution explorer in VS 2019 here:

[image]

Here I want Az Module as a package. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can set the powershell gallery as package source in visual studio, then you can manage it as a package.**

The steps:

1. Go to Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources
2. Create a new package source.
3. Type the source: https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
   [image]
4. Right-click the project > Click "Manage Nuget Packages..."
5. Switch the Package Source to the new source.

[image]

6. Click [image: Refresh] button, then install Az Module

[image]